# Refactoring LINQ statement using Entity Framework to a method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, methods

I have these Linq queries that I use multiple times in my code. I want to make a method of them and return their results.

```
var myevent = (from v in myEntities.Events
                           where _EventID == v.EventID
                           select v).SingleOrDefault();

var comments = (from c in myEntities.Fora
                            orderby c.DateCreated descending
                            where c.EventID == _EventID
                            select c).ToList();
```

Comment: Alright, do you need permission? Do you have a question?

Comment: so return myevent and comments from a method...?

Comment: Hi, I'm reviewing your question as this is your first question on Stackoverflow. Please make sure to have a specific question that ends with a "?" somewhere in your description. This will help user figure out what you need.

Comment: BTW, you could shorten to var myevent = myEntities.Events.SingleOrDefault(e => e.EventId == _EventId);

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but it sounds like you just want two methods to return the results of the linq query.

```
public Events GetEvent(int id)
{
    return (from v in myEntities.Events
           where _EventID == id
           select v).SingleOrDefault();
}

public List<Fora> GetComments(int id)
{
     return (from c in myEntities.Fora
             orderby c.DateCreated descending
             where c.EventID == id
             select c).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has too many unknowns to answer concretely, and this is something the SO is particular about.

I'm going to assume your entity is DB-backed.

You need to be aware of the transaction scope.  You could use a separate class with a static "myEntities" and implement as Anonymous above.  However if different threads are calling in you may end up with a nested transaction.  You also don't want to create a new connection every time you call it.

I would implement this as part of a broader data access layer and pass your connection to it as part of the constructor. If you choose to use a static method then you should pass the connection as one of the params.

Or you could have an abstract class with this logic, and have child classes implement it.

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity. This is the first time I've posted a question and I thought I was giving all the relevant information. yes it is DB- backed. My goal is to pass a variable named _EventID to this method and have it return a record that I can use to populate fields like this: 

lblEventTitle.Text = myevent.EventTitle;